# How to handle Error Codes in AWS S3 using Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to handle an exception in TS.  Specifically I want to handle exceptions with the error code NoSuchKey.  The problem I am running into is that I am unable to cast the error or find this property (There is no NoSuchKeyError type).  I come from a C# background so I am still getting used to TS typing.  Here is what I have:

```
const client = new S3Client(...);
const command = new GetObjectCommand(...)

let response: GetObjectCommandOutput;
try {
 response = await client.send(command);
} 
catch (error: any) {
   if (error.code === "NoSuchKey") {
     console.log(error);
     return;
  }
}
```

I'm using: @aws-sdk/client-s3 version 3.48.0

Comment: before your catch `if` conditional, try `console.log(error.name)`

Comment: No problem! added more context for you (and future readers) in my answer below! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in JavaScript (and by extension, Typescript) exception names can be accessed via [`Error.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error):

> Error.prototype.name
>
> ```
>  Error name.
> ```

and based on the [AWS SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html#troubleshooting), we know that this is also the case here:

```js
try {
  const data = await client.send(command);
  // process data.
} catch (error) {
  const { requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId } = error.$metadata;
  console.log({ requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId });
  /**
   * The keys within exceptions are also parsed.
   * You can access them by specifying exception names:
   * if (error.name === 'SomeServiceException') {
   *     const value = error.specialKeyInException;
   * }
   */
}
```